# Why is Binding 6 not supplied?? Sqlite/Python/Tkinter

Tags: python, database, sqlite, tkinter

I am trying to make a function that will save the changes I make to the values in my database using SQLite in an app I made with `TkInter`. The values that exist are inserted onto an entry box that the user can then use to make changes. I want them to then be able to click a button with the command "save_changes" and have the values in the database be updated. This is my code for command Save_Changes

```
def Save_Changes():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('Database')
    C = conn.cursor()
    C.execute("""UPDATE Database SET
        Buinsess_Name = :Buisness_Name,
        Customer_Name = :Customer_Name,
        Address_1 = :Address_1,
        City = :City,      
        State = :State,
        Zip_Code = :Zip_code,
        Phone_Number = :Phone_Number
        WHERE oid = :oid""",
    {
        'Buisness_Name' : Buisness_Name2.get(),
        'Customer_Name' : Contact_Name2.get(),
        'Address_1' : Address_1B.get(),
        'City' : City2.get(),
        'State' : State2.get(),
        'Zip_Code' : Zip_Code2.get(),
        'Phone_Number' : Phone_Number2.get(),
        'oid' : Update_Box.get()

    })


    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

This works fine on a video tutorial I saw, but for me I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/Program1/PART 1.py", line 161, in Save_Changes
    C.execute("""UPDATE Database SET
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: You did not supply a value for binding 6.
```

I cant find what's wrong with binding 6?? This is the original table I created

```
C.execute ("""CREATE TABLE Database (
        Buinsess_Name text,
        Customer_Name text,
        Address_1 text,
        City text,
        State text,
        Zip_Code integer,
        Phone_Number integer
        )""")
```

Also I already made the text box names global variables because they were created elsewhere in the program. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Case problem:

```
Zip_Code = :Zip_code
```

Should be

```
Zip_Code = :Zip_Code
```